# Authenticate multiple users for single login?

Tags: sql-server

Running `SQL Server 2014` with multiple client computers. I want all clients to log on to the server with their own username and unique password. However, I would like to use the same server login for all of them. Or, if possible, skip the server login entirely. Is this possible? They will only be granted access to ONE database, no matter what...

The reason why I want to do this is to avoid the extra work for the system administrator. Adding new server logins for each new user soon becomes tiresome.

Comment: If the SQL server is in Active Directory domain, you can create a login with AD group, so every member of the group will be able to use the server with windows authentication.

Comment: That sounds like a really good solution. But what if Active Directory cannot be used?

Comment: Windows Login (AD) is the preferred approach to securing SQL Server. As Evgeni says then it is simply a case of adding users to an AD Group and securing access to the SQL Server by CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<groupName>] FROM WINDOWS;

Comment: When you say "log on to the server", does that mean literally connecting straight to the database? Or are they going to be using an application that connects to the database on their behalf? If the latter, you could use something like the ASP.NET membership provider. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @BenThul, well, I have a client software that needs to connect directly to the database using `SqlConnection`. However, this might be possible to change. Would the `ASP.NET membership provider` work for a heavy client?

Comment: I don't see why not. On the database side, it creates a set of objects for managing users and roles. You'd need to modify your application to be apprised of these, but that shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @BenThul, but the client needs to log on to the server using credentials that are accepted by the actual database server. Or do you mean that the client would *talk* to the `ASP.NET membership provider` instead of the database server?

Comment: The latter. The alternatives have already been expressed if you want more than one person to map to a server-level principal. In SQL Server, the only way to accomplish this is through an AD group.